# jQuery : Scroll To - Change the div ID

Tags: jquery, css, html, scroll, scrollto

I have a problem with jQuery, I want to change a DIV (not the content of the DIV but the DIV NAME div id="DIVNAME") when the scrollbar is at 20px.

Before scrollbar = 20px :

> divname {
>   width: 1012px;
>   margin: 25px auto 0 auto;
>   height: 50px;
>   }

After scrollbar + 20px :

> divname2 {
>   width: 1012px;
>   margin: 25px auto 0 auto;
>   height: 50px;
>   **position: fixed;**
>   }

My specific case :

[image http://i.minus.com/jjjWR2hKWhhFw.jpg](http://i.minus.com/jjjWR2hKWhhFw.jpg)

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this way, like adding a class to the parent `div` to make it fixed. Will post the code and fiddle shortly.

Yup done with the code:

### JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
       if($(".check").offset().top < $(window).scrollTop())
           $(".check").addClass("fixed");
        else
           $(".check").removeClass("fixed"); 
    });
});​
```

### CSS

```
​ul, ol, p, li {padding: 5px 0;}
h1 {font: 2em Tahoma bold; text-align: center;}
div.check.fixed h1 {position: fixed; top: 0; width: 100%; background: #fff;}
```

### HTML

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

<div class="check">
    <h1>To be fixed!</h1>
</div>

<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>

<p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>

<ol>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>

<p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>

<p>The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</p>​
```

### Fiddle

Watch it live at http://jsfiddle.net/ekeSL/

### Changing the name of the `div`

It is not advisable to change the `id` of the `div`. But still if you insist on it, you can do so by this way:

```
$("div").attr("id", "newId");
```

Comment: Ty !
PS : The menu is aligned (right&left: auto) I don't know if its a problem

Comment: @user1480883 Check out the fiddle. :) Hope it helps! :)

Comment: @user1480883 That is not an issue. It doesn't cause any problem as the layout of the parent will be positioned! :)

Answer (score 1):

If all you're changing is the `position`, it might be easier to add a class or append the css attribute.

```
if (scrollbar > 20px)
    $("#divname").css("position" : "fixed");
```

Comment: No, I have to make other changes.